# Loading PDF at a specific page with pdf.js viewer

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js and the included viewer to display pdfs on my website.
I added a menu to the viewer, where users can choose a specific bookmark of different pdf files.
If a users is clicking on a menu item the file should be opened and jumping to a specific page.

So far I managed it to open a new pdf file but I didn't find a way to open it at a specific page. I tried it this way:

```
PDFView.open(src + "/" + dest.file);
PDFView.page = dest.page;
```

I know, I can use the `#page=` hashtag when opening the viewer for the first time, but that's not working when I'm loading other files after the viewer is already opened.

Is there any why to solve this problem? Maybe something like a event-listener I can call after the new file is successfully loaded, so I can jump to the page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to reset the `initialBookmark` value before opening the file:

```
PDFView.initialBookmark = "page=10";
PDFView.open(src + "/" + dest.file);
```

Comment: I hoped there is an event-listener (I could use it in some other situations), but your solution works, too. Thx ;)