# Linking to named destinations in a PDF from an R Shiny App

Tags: html, r, pdf, shiny

I have a PDF with named destinations that I am trying to link to from an R Shiny web app. I am able to successfully link to the PDF, however when attempting to link to specific named destinations by appending #nameddest=name, the app opens the PDF to the title page instead of the named destination. Inspecting the hyperlink shows the correct .pdf#nameddest=name link to the named location, but clicking on the link opens the PDF to the first page and the address shown in the browser's location bar does not include #namedest-name. I think Shiny or Google Chrome may have excluded the URL fragment for some reason.

- I've used a simple naming convention for the destinations of all lowercase alphabetical characters without spaces, periods, hyphens, underscores, etc.
- I am able to access the named destinations successfully by manually appending the url fragment #nameddest=name to the pdf address in the browser's location bar.

Any advice in getting the links to work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How a document is opened and displayed to the user is 99% under the control of the rendering app, whether it be Acrobat or [`PDF.js`](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). For the latter, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/14798342/3358272 is useful, but for everything else I don't know if there's a standard.